# Zurb Foundation dropdown menu fails in Firefox

Tags: firefox, zurb-foundation, dropdown

I have a dropdown menu at apao.org. I inserted this code at the bottom of the page to get the dropdowns to collapse properly on mouseout of the dropdown area (they were staying open before unless you exited through the trigger element in the nav bar). It works everywhere, but broke something in Firefox. Now the menu shows for a second in Firefox and then disappears when mousing off the trigger element in the nav bar (so you can't move your mouse down to actually select anything).

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $('.has-dropdown').on('mouseout', function () {
             $(this).find('.dropdown').hide()
         });

         $('.has-dropdown').on('mousemove', function () {
             $(this).find('.dropdown').show()
         });
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: can you provide the javascript where you initialize the dropdownMenus?  Is this happening in responsive layout or full screen?

Comment: i looked at the page and saw the error, but the menus aren't using data attributes, so they must be initialized in javascript.  For example is the autoClose option set?

Comment: Autoclose is not set. Can you point me to that? Much appreciated!

Comment: Also note that this unintended Firefox behavior occurs ONLY on the home page of the site.

Comment: see [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html) under plugin options.  The fact that it is only firefox, and only the home page probably means it is not this option...but hope it helps